# list variables in an embed discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to list every "action" variables from my file in an embed. The embed should look like this:

```
Title: Action list
description: 
action1
action2
action3
... and so on
```

Here is what I got:

```
  if(message.content.startsWith(`${config.prefix}actionlist`)){
    let list
    let actionsFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data/actions.json"))
    actionsFile.forEach(action => {
        //push action.name in the list

    })
    const embed = new MessageEmbed() //embed 
    .setColor(`#FF0000`)
    .setTitle('Action list')
    .setDescription(`${list}`)
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    

  }
```

An action looks like this:

```
  {
    "name": "shoes",
    "price": 154
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map each item to their name, join them by a line break and use the returning value.

```js
const actions = actionsFile
   .map(action => action.name)
   .join('\n');

...

.setDescription(actions);
```